# Exporting Google Firebase to Bigquery

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I am trying to export my Google Firebase database to Google Bigquery but have not found a solution besides manually exporting everything. I have found multiple ways to export firebase analytics but this is not what I want. Any help or anything that would point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks to all!

- Wes

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is only supported in an automated way for Analytics.

You could probably write a script to load from backups[1], but you would need some intermediate processing to get them into the newline-delimited JSON format that BigQuery requires. You'd also want to decide how to split the tree structure into multiple tables.

It may be worth adding a feature request to their public issue tracker (if the Firebase team has one).

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/backups

Answer (score 0):

## Manual export/import

If you wish to do a one-time export/import, you can do this manually. When viewing the Firebase Database console, click on the three-dot icon for more options. One of those options is "Export JSON", which will download a file to your computer.  You may also be able to use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-get) to perform the same operation if you'd prefer to download the file to a server.

After downloading the database export, you can try following the documentation for [loading data into BigQuery from a file](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data).  Depending on your Database structure, you may need to reformat/restructure the data to be compatible with what BigQuery expects.

## Streaming export/import

If you need to stream data from your Database into BigQuery, you can use [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/). For example, you can write a function [triggered by a Database-event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events) which uses the [BigQuery NodeJS client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries#client-libraries-install-nodejs) to stream that data to your BigQuery table.

Be sure to familiarize yourself with the associated [costs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/controlling-costs) & [quotas](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#streaminginserts), as well as the docs about [streaming data into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery).